# How does *(array + 3) work?

Tags: c, arrays

I am studying for my midterm. this was an example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void doubleArray(int array[], int length) 
 {
for (int i = 0; i < length-2; i++) {
        array[i] += array[i];
 }
     length += 5;
     printf(“%d\n”, length); // Question 29
 }


int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
     int integers[6] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
     int length = 6;


printf(“%d\n”, integers[4]); // Question 28
doubleArray(integers, length);
printf(“%d\n”, *(integers + 3)); // Question 30
printf(“%d\n”, *(integers + 4)); // Question 31
printf(“%d\n”, length); // Question 32
}
```

for questions 30 and 31
the answer is that it prints 12 (30) and 7 (31)
can someone explain to me why and what that "*(integers + 3)" means?

Comment: It means the same thing as `integers[3]`, by definition.

Comment: printf(“%d\n”, *(integers + 3)), So then how does it print out to be 12?

Comment: It was doubled by doubleArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`*` is a dereference operator on a pointer.**

This means that it will "get" the value that's stored at the pointer address of the item right after it (`(integers + 3)`).

It will interpret this value as the dereferenced type of the item after it (`int` since `(integers + 3)` is of type `int*`)

**(integers + 3)**

`integers` is a pointer to the address of the first element of the `integers` array.

That means that if `integers` contained `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` then it would point to where `1` is stored in memory.

`integers + 3` takes the address of `integers` (i.e. where `1` is stored in memory) and adds the amount of address space required to store 3 `int`s  (since the pointer is of type `int*`).  Advancing it by one space would give you the address of `2` in memory, advancing it by two spaces would give you the address of `3` in memory, and advancing it by three spaces gives you the address of `4` in memory.

**How this applies to your example**

`(integers + 3)` gives you the address of the 4th item in the `integers` array since it's the first element's address plus the size of three elements.

Dereferencing that with the `*` operator, gives you the value of the 4th element, `12` (since the value of `6` was doubled by `doubleArray`)

The same applies to `*(integers + 4)` except that `doubleArray` didn't double the 5th element so it gives you `7`.

**How `doubleArray` works**

`for (int i = 0; i < length-2; i++)` means start the variable `i` at 0 and advance it until it is `length - 2`.

This means it takes the value of everything from `0` to the value of `length - 2` but executes the body of the loop for values from `0` to `length - 3` since the `<` is exclusive (the conditional is evaluated BEFORE executing the body of the loop so when `i == length - 2` the condition is `false` and the loop terminates without further execution.

So, for each element, excluding the last two, the element in `array` is added to itself.

Comment: Good luck with your midterm!